# Linear transformation, when unknown value

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given *(f)* matrix $$A =\begin{bmatrix}k-2 & -2\\1 & k\end{bmatrix}$$ is a linear transformation.

How to solve *k* when *f* describes vector (1,3) to vector (-5,10) in terms of standard basis?

(Sorry, english is not my native language, so I hope I translated this so that you can understand the question).

Comment: Just calculate it. What is the vector that you get if you calculate $A(1,3)^T$? That must be equal to..? Can you solve for $k$ then? It is very simple believe me just calculate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}k-2 & -2\\1 & k\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1\\3\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}k-2 -6\\1+3k\end{bmatrix}
$$

so we want:
$$
k-8=-5 \qquad \mbox{and}\qquad 1+3k=10
$$

Can you find a value of $k$ that satisfies these two equations?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$(-5\text{  }10)=\begin{bmatrix}k-2 & -2\\1 & k\end{bmatrix}(1\text{  }3)^{T}.$$
Solve for $k$ to get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have that the *Linear Transformation $f$* send the vector $(1,3)$ to $(-5,10)$.

You're given the matrix of $f$, so you have :

$$f = A\vec{x} =\begin{bmatrix}k-2 & -2\\1 & k\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y\end{bmatrix} = ((k-2)x -2y, x + ky) $$

By the points you were given, you get the linear system for $f(1,3)=((k-2)-6,1+3k)$ :

$$\begin{cases} (k-2) - 6 = -5 \\ 1 + 3k = 10 \end{cases}$$

You only have one unknown though, and by solving the first equation, you get that : $k=3$.